# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character on line 1 : Angular 5 Http call(Angular JS was working fine)

Tags: json, angular, http, rxjs, angular5

I have a Spring REST service which gives a byte array. Previously I was using angularjs 1. Using FileSaver, I was able to download the pdf which is sent from REST service on the the response of a HTTP POST call.

Now, I am migrating my changes to angular 5. This is my HTTP post call in service -

```
testPDF(abc: FormArray): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
    const options = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
             'response-type': 'blob'
       })
     }
     return this.http.post<HttpResponse<any>>('/myRestPath', abc, options);
}
```

On my component typescript file I have subscribed like this -

```
xyz() {
    this.myService.testPDF(this.abc.value).subscribe((file: any) => console.log('done'));
}
```

I have verified my REST service. It returns proper byte array. I have tried several other workarounds available on the internet. But nothing seems to be working. In browser console I could see the response, which looks to be a PDF in byte stream. In console I could see 3-4 MB size received, which make me believe that I have received the data but couldn't subscribe it. HTTP response code is also 200.

It looks like by default, the response is tried to be fetched as a JSON instead of BLOB. As my response doesn't start with '{', while parsing the data it couldn't parse the response. I am not asking anyone to write code for me. For downloading PDF file also, I can do it using FileSaver.

The key problem I am facing is why my application is not entering into the subscribe block and execute the console statement.

Comment: Show `abc` method of `myService`;

Comment: Sorry. My bad. Abc method is the testPDF one. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are setting the response type on the `headers`, but `HttpClient` expects it to be set on the `responseType` property of the `options`.

For `HttpClient` the following update would work

```
testPDF(abc: FormArray): Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>> {
    return this.http.post('/myRestPath', abc, {
        observe: 'response',
        responseType: 'blob' 
    });
}
```

A complete example which works for me with a `GET`, provided there is a PDF file with the name `some.pdf` under the `assets` directory.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class MyNewService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getSomePDF():  Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>>{
    return this.http.get('/assets/some.pdf',  {
      observe: 'response',
      responseType: 'blob' 
    });
  }
}
```

For older ones using `@angular/http`, you can use the `ResponseContentType` enum with an `import { ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';`

```
 const options = {
     responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob 
 }
```

API docs [here](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post).

Comment: When I set response type like this, I am getting compilation error while setting options as a 3rd argument on http post. It's showing "Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"json'".

Comment: @pradiptagure updated answer to cover more versions of Angular.

Comment: Having the same issue still. It's still giving same compilation error.

Comment: I am using latest version of angular.

Comment: @pradiptagure can you check the latest update to the answer

Comment: I think for angular 5 HTTP Client, API documentation is wrong. The code you added is based on the API documentation, which will give compilation error I mentioned in my earlier comments. There are GitHub issues as well for that. Http client of angular 5 will always return a JSON data. I have to use deprecated HTTP API to make my code work. Let me know in case you think something else.

Comment: @pradiptagure, did you ever get this working? If so, what do you have to do. I'm in the same boat as you were.